# High level Consumer manual offset

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

Hello I m actually trying to implement a high level consumer code and instead of auto commit i want to use manual commit.My main purpose is that when i commit the offset and again restart the consumer it does not show the old and read messages.
I implemented the below code.Plz Help me.

```
    public VulabKafkaConsumer(String a_zookeeper, String a_groupId, String a_topic) {
        consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(
                createConsumerConfig(a_zookeeper, a_groupId));
        this.topic = a_topic;
    }

    public void run() {
        Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(1));
        Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
        List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
        for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
            ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();

            while (it.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println("Message : " + new String(it.next().message()));
                consumer.commitOffsets();
            }
        }
    }

    private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig(String a_zookeeper, String a_groupId) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("zookeeper.connect", "localhost:2181");
        props.put("group.id", "test-group");
        props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "500");
        props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
        props.put("auto.commit.enable","false");
        props.put("offsets.storage","kafka");
        //props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "");

        return new ConsumerConfig(props);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String zooKeeper =  "localhost:2181";
        String groupId = "test-group";
        String topic = "test1";
        //int threads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        VulabKafkaConsumer example = new VulabKafkaConsumer(zooKeeper, groupId, topic);
        example.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been in the same scenario but using kafka version 0.9, is necessary to specify:

```
auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

if this property is not setting then by default it's value is "latest". This property is to tell kafka how to do when there is not initial offset or if the current offset does not exist any more because data has been deleted. I believe for the version you are using the value that you need to set is "smallest" otherwise default value is "largest"